# There are no carriers that deliver to the address you selected in Dhl Module using prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I used Dhl shipping module in prestashop. At backoffoice, I configured North America zone  to Dhl shipping carrier

```
My frontend :-

My account Details with address :-
User name :- test@gmail.com
Password  :- test
Address details :- 
State :- New York ,
Postal Code :- 10003,
Country  :- United States
```

But I got Below Error :-
"There are no carriers that deliver to the address you selected". How Can I fix this .

Answer (score 0):

Problem of no carrier on the selected address is  because of all the country are set to disable in default. just enabled all the countries and it will work.

Also check [this](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Managing+Shipping) and [this](https://mypresta.eu/en/art/basic-tutorials/there-are-no-carriers-that-deliver-to-the-address-you-selected-issue-how-to-fix.html)

I hope it will help you ..

Comment: In my backoffice I enabled  all countries and zones .